# How can I find the bad setstate in my code?

Tags: react-native, setstate

My react native code seems to execute appropriately. I still keep getting a bad setstate code error. Here is the error:

```bash
Warning: Cannot update a component (`ForwardRef(BaseNavigationContainer)`) while rendering a different component (`Login`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `Login`, follow the stack trace as described in https://reactjs.org/link/setstate-in-render
  >> in Login (created by SceneView)
```

I was able to trace it back to this line (I think at least): Login  @   Login.js:16

It would be this part of the code:

```js
export function Login({navigation}){
  if (auth.currentUser) {
    navigation.navigate('Root')
  } else {
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      if (user) {
        navigation.navigate("Root")
      } 
    });
  }
```

Here is the the entire component that appears to have the bad setState. I can't seem to figure out how to get this error to go away. All the code seems to be working ok, though...

```jsx
export function Login({ navigation }) {
  if (auth.currentUser) {
    navigation.navigate("Root");
  } else {
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      if (user) {
        navigation.navigate("Root");
      }
    });
  }

  let [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = React.useState("");
  let [email, setEmail] = React.useState("");
  let [password, setPassword] = React.useState("");

  let login = () => {
    if (email !== "" && password !== "") {
      signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
        .then((userCredential) => {
          // Signed in
          navigation.navigate("Home", { user: userCredential.user });
          // ...
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          setErrorMessage(error.message);
        });
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={AppStyles.loginContainer}>
      <KeyboardAvoidingView
        style={AppStyles.backgroundCover}
        behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : null}
        keyboardVerticalOffset={60}
      >
        <View style={AppStyles.loginScreen}>
          <Text style={AppStyles.textHeader}>Login</Text>
          <Text style={AppStyles.errorText}>{errorMessage}</Text>
          <TextInput
            style={AppStyles.input}
            placeholder="Email"
            placeholderTextColor={"#fff"}
            value={email}
            onChangeText={setEmail}
          />
          <TextInput
            style={AppStyles.input}
            placeholder="Password"
            placeholderTextColor={"#fff"}
            secureTextEntry={true}
            passwordRules={{ required: true, minLength: 6 }}
            value={password}
            onChangeText={setPassword}
          />
          <View style={AppStyles.rowContainer}>
            <Text style={AppStyles.text}>Don't have an account? </Text>
            <TextButton
              size={"20px"}
              text={"Sign Up"}
              color={"#fff"}
              onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Signup")}
            />
          </View>
          <View style={AppStyles.rowContainer}>
            <Text style={AppStyles.text}>Forgot your password? </Text>
            <TextButton
              size={"20px"}
              text={"Reset"}
              color={"#fff"}
              onPress={() => navigation.navigate("ResetPassword")}
            />
          </View>
          <TextButton
            size={"20px"}
            text={"Login"}
            backgroundColor="#83C9F4"
            paddingVertical={6}
            paddingHorizontal={12}
            onPress={login}
          />
        </View>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Where do the `auth` variable comes from?

Comment: @devpolo looks like Firebase

Comment: Obviously. Thanks @Phil

Comment: Where does `navigation` come from in this component's props?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always wait for your component to be fully mounted before any navigation action.

Can you try to add your navigation logic into a `useEffect`?

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (auth.currentUser) {
    navigation.navigate('Root')
  }

  const subscriber = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
    if (user) {
      navigation.navigate("Root")
    } 
  });

  return subscriber
}, [])
```